# How is rocketry funding divided by sources throughout the ages?

Tags: rockets, history, cost

It can be argued that first rocket in history was a steam powered pigeon in 400 BCE. Around 1200 CE, the Chinese were using rocket powered weapons of war. Beginning around 1960, both the Americans and the Russians had major government funded scientific rocket and space exploration programs in place. Presently (2013), we're seeing an increasing involvement of privately funded rocket research.

Is it possible to report the funding for rocket research and/or construction by the three major sources: military, private and government?

Reference: [Brief History of Rockets (NASA)](http://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/k-12/TRC/Rockets/history_of_rockets.html)

Comment: This question has promise, but I'm not sure it is really on topic here. You might have a better audience at [opendata.se].

Comment: +1  for good question.  Would be an interesting comparison to compare these results with the results for, say, opening the new world in the late 1400s+.

Comment: Are you looking for data about funding of 1) space exploration, 2) rockets used in space exploration, or 3) rockets used for any purpose?

Comment: The question is ill-posed. Military is part of government, and private funding was in place only before 1934 and after ~2000, and it was a joke compared to gov't spending.

Comment: We are not seeing private rocket research. We can see development, testing and evaluation, but not much **privately-funded research**.

Comment: @Joe #3 for any purpose, while the funding might be for  scientific research, military supremacy or capitalistic and the goal may a rocket to power a fire work, or reach the edge of space, it all benefits the science as a whole.

Comment: @DeerHunter good points and dividing the scientific vs military funding of government may be difficult, also the line between private and government financing of pure scientific study in education is hard to define.  But I believe that funding is often (*usually?*) requested to benefit one of these three categories. As Erik points out it would make for an interesting comparison, but the question is first about if it is possible to answer, and second to provide the answer.  It all hinges on how funding is recorded in history, maybe the answer is that funding can not divided.

Comment: James, funding *is* broken into RDT&E, production, and maintenance. You can have a look at overall patterns in two places, for a start: [Public Budget Database](http://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/default/files/omb/budget/fy2014/assets/outlays.xls) (Excel) and [Science and Engineering Indicators 2012](http://www.nsf.gov/statistics/seind12/appendix.htm). The United States has the data, at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments this question has received, it does not appear possible to divide funding by the three categories given.  Both Military and scientific government funding are the same source, and the designation between them is merely a political preference of the time.

Private funding, as a commercial speculation as of 2013 is essentially insignificant.